# Send request to check cookie from other domain

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I have domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com and centraldomain.com.

I want to have connected login/sign-up across domain1, domain2 and domain3 so I'm going to set all their login forms to submit to centraldomain.com/login.php. Then I can create a session on that site and send a curl request to check that session when a user visits any of the other 3 domains. I think this would work (correct me if I'm wrong).

But I want to go a step further - I'd like centraldomain.com/login.php to create a cookie, and when the user visits any of the other sites they can send a request to centraldomain.com to check if there's a cookie active.

To sum up, I'd like domain1 to be able to ask centraldomain if it has a cookie for the current visitor and get some of the cookie data in response.

This is the cURL code I'm using to (try to) set the cookie. However, it's not working:

```
$ch = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.centraldomain.com/fantasy/login.php");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                            http_build_query(array('par1' => $par1, 'par2' => $par2)));

                // receive server response ...
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

                curl_close ($ch);
```

And this is login.php on centraldomain.com:

```
$par1=$_POST['par1'];
$par2=$_POST['par2'];

$cookievalue=$email."_____".$cryptedpass;
$date_of_expiry=time()+60*60;

setcookie("fantasylogin", $cookievalue, $date_of_expiry, "/" );var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

When I open this page on centraldomain.com directly, it sets a cookie. But the curl request does nothing. SO naturally I need to get this right before I can even request the cookie content back. speaking of that, I was told it can be done but it doesn't make sense to me. The cookie is connected to the user agent. So if you send a curl request (as opposed to opening the page in a browser) how does the target script even know what user agent the visitor is using? How can it identify the cookie for that visitor? Is it necessary to somehow send user agent identification along with the request?

If curl won't work, can you propose a different solution? I've been thinking some invisible forms and iframes could do the trick, but I'd rather not deal with that if I don't have to.

Let's please leave security issues out of it for now (regarding cookie content and general cookie-related concerns). I will add proper safety mechanisms once I have the basic version working.

Comment: Have a look at [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), [SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on), [OpenID](http://openid.net/), [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) and [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be done with curl requests. User's browser must handle the cookie. Also you can not set/read a cookie to/from another domain. So you have to do a little front-end work.

This is how I would do it:

1. When user log ins from domain1.com, send make an ajax request to centraldomain.com and get a unique key that will be saved in database for that user.
2. Set a cookie to domain1.com. (e.g userID=yourKey)
3. Create a page that takes your unique key as a parameter, validates it from database and sets as the cookie value that will make your server understand user is logged in. (a cookie named userID in this scenario)
4. Make ajax calls to other servers with your unique key **from user's browser**. (To the page that takes key as parameter)
5. Check user login with searching cookie value in your database.

This will set cookies to all domains, and user will be logged in to all of them. Assuming they all use same database and have right crossdomain.xml configuration so that they can make ajax calls to each other.

And when user log outs, just set that user's unique key to NULL. This will make user log out all of websites.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But what happens when the user deletes his browser cookies? Our sites (other than the one that set the cookie) can't check that so they will just check the database table and think he is still logged in. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: In this case, you can set user's unique key to NULL if cookie doesn't exist, but I assume user makes another request to same domain after manually deleting its cookie. There is another guarantee way but it is more complicated. You can send ajax calls to all domains to check if cookie exist on all of them, and if not delete the database key. But this has to be done on every page visit and you need to hide page until this process is over. Not nice.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to understand how cookie works in general.
What happens when you execute `setcookie`?

A following response-header appends to headers.

```
Set-Cookie: UserID=JohnDoe; Max-Age=3600; Version=1
```

And after that when response is received it's a work of a browser to store it (or not store if this functionality is not supported or disabled)

So when you send it from your app through curl - your app receives this response, and it doesn't care about `Set-Cookie`.
If you will resend this header to user from your domain1 the cookie will be stored for this domain1.

And btw you won't be able to check the cookie from other domain behind the scene, since all the cookies stored in browser's storage and sends along with the request to the server.

What you are trying to do is some sort of OAuth and it's much more complicated than just `setcookie`. You can try to use some of the existing server\client libraries from its site http://oauth.net/2/